# Formatting not coming out perfect

Tags: python, list, formatting, tuples

The code I have loops through a list of tuples and displays them in what I thought would give me a nice table but instead of having a nice table when it displays them they begin to go out of formatting and look awful.

```
for i in range(0,(len(l)-1)):
        print("{:<30s}{:<30s}{:<6s}{:<15s}£{:>6s}".format(l[i][4],l[i][3]\
                                                    ,l[i][0],l[i][2],l[i][1]))
```

[image: Here's how the spacing looks awful.]

Each row is a tuple containing five variables. Is the spacing fine and it's just how my computer displays it or is there something wrong with the formatting code I've used?

Also, using formatting how do I make each one have the surname with a comma directly after it and the salary have the '£' directly before it.

Thank you.

Comment: Please write the data you are using (no, the image is not enough since I cannot copy-paste it into a terminal, and we don't have much time to copy data by hand). Also, try to write the output on a file and open it with a text editor that uses a monospaced font. In this way you can check whether it's a problem of the terminal. The formatting code should be fine except that you should really use `for value in l: print("...".format(value[4], value[3], ..))` instead of iterating over the indices. If you need both the value *and* the index then use `for i,value in enumerate(l)`.

Comment: Why are you using `range(0,(len(l)-1))` instead of `range(0,len(l))`?

Comment: @martineau why range is even used, it can be `for r in l:` instead

Comment: @alko: There may be a reason if the OP is trying to avoid printing the last element of the list on purpose -- it can still be done without indexing but I want to know if it's on purpose.

Comment: JamesDonnelly: The space formatting looks basically OK. Everything won't all line up properly however unless it'se displayed with a mono-spaced font, like Courier, Consolas, Lucida Console, or Monaco, to name several.

Comment: @martineau little mistake from me. Thought that if the first entry of a list was 0 the last would be the length of the list - 1. Still a little confused actually.

Comment: JamesDonnelly: Easy mistake -- in which case you could use just `range(len(l))` because `range` starts at `0` and only goes to the value `len(l)-1` by default which very convenient for indexing lists. However, whenever you find yourself wanting to do something like that, it's often easier (a a little faster) to use `for item in list:` and not need to index the list for each item in it at all.

Answer (score 0):

```
# -*- coding: cp1252 -*-

pat = "{:<30s}{:<30s}{:<6s}{:<15s}£{:>6s}"

l = [("12345",'35000','Consultant','Bart','Simpson'),
      ("12346","25000","Teacher","Ned","Flanders")]

d = dict.fromkeys(xrange(5))
for x in l:
    for i in xrange(5):
        d[i] = max(d[i],len(x[i]))
print '\n'.join('%s : %d' % item for item in d.iteritems())

pat = "{4:<%s} {3:<%s} {0:<%s} {2:<%s} £{1:>%s}"\
      %(d[4],d[3],d[0],d[2],d[1])

for x in l:
    print pat.format(*x)
```

But with Pandas it would be even more simple. Let me some time to add a solution with Pandas

Comment: @martineau From _"instead of having a nice table when it displays them they begin to go out of formatting"_ and _"Is the spacing fine and it's just how my computer displays it or is there something wrong with the formatting code I've used"_ , it seemed to me that he is not satisfied of the too long spaces between the columns. But reading again his question, there are requirements that aren't fulfilled in my answer